# Подключение джойстика в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Подключаю функционал джойстрика как описано в документации по Qt: http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qgamepad.html

Как программно узнать, подключен ли вообще джойстик или нет?

Comment: `QGamepad::isConnected()` же, не?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qgamepad.html#connected-prop

Comment: @Fat-Zer не дочитал... спасибо